# Taking data from multiple links while storing in one item in Scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am currently working my way through learning the basics of web-scraping via Scraby, and have run into a particular issue of items being duplicated rather than expanded.

The first page I scrape data from has a selection of links that I need to follow to scrape an additional link from.  These links are stored as item['link'].

My issue is that by iterating over these links, via requests nested inside a loop, the results are not being appended to the original item instance but are instead being returned as new instances.

The results therefore look a bit like the following:

```
{'date': [u'29 June 2015', u'15 September 2015'],
'desc': [u'Audit Committee - 29 June 2015',
      u'Audit Committee - 15 September 2015'],
'link': [u'/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-29-June-2015',
      u'/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-15-September-2015'],
'pdf_url': 'http://www.antrimandnewtownabbey.gov.uk/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-15-September-2015',
'title': [u'2015']}

{'date': [u'29 June 2015', u'15 September 2015'],
'desc': [u'Audit Committee - 29 June 2015',
      u'Audit Committee - 15 September 2015'],
'link': [u'/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-29-June-2015',
      u'/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-15-September-2015'],
'pdf_url': 'http://www.antrimandnewtownabbey.gov.uk/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-29-June-2015',
'title': [u'2015']}
```

where as I want them to be contained in the same object like the following:

```
{'date': [u'29 June 2015', u'15 September 2015'],
'desc': [u'Audit Committee - 29 June 2015',
      u'Audit Committee - 15 September 2015'],
'link': [u'/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-29-June-2015',
      u'/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-15-September-2015'],
'pdf_url': [u'http://www.antrimandnewtownabbey.gov.uk/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-29-June-2015',
      u'http://www.antrimandnewtownabbey.gov.uk/Council/Council-and-Committee-Minutes/Audit-Committee/2015/Audit-Committee-15-September-2015'],
'title': [u'2015']}
```

Here's my current implementations (based mainly of the Scrapy tutorials):

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="lower-col-right"]'):
        item = CouncilExtractorItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('header[@class="intro user-content font-set clearfix"] /h1/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="user-content"] /section[@class="listing-item"]/a/@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="user-content"] /section[@class="listing-item"]/a/h2/text()').extract()
        item['date'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="user-content"] /section[@class="listing-item"]/span/text()').extract()
        for url in item['link']:
            full_url = response.urljoin(url)
            request = scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_page2)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['pdf'] = response.url
    return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your inner XPath expressions *context-specific* by prepending a dot:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="lower-col-right"]'):
    item = CouncilExtractorItem()
    item['title'] = sel.xpath('.//header[@class="intro user-content font-set clearfix"]/h1/text()').extract()
    item['link'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="user-content"]/section[@class="listing-item"]/a/@href').extract()
    item['desc'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="user-content"]/section[@class="listing-item"]/a/h2/text()').extract()
    item['date'] = sel.xpath('.//div[@class="user-content"]/section[@class="listing-item"]/span/text()').extract()
    # ...
```

Comment: I gave this a try, but there must be something else wrong with my code that is causing the issue.

Comment: @user5520937 are you sure you've tried with `.//` at the beginning of every inner xpath?

Comment: Yep - that was the final problem I was having - thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a combination of the following two chunks of code working together:

```
    for url in item['link']:
        full_url = response.urljoin(url)
        request = scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_page2)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request
```

and

```
    def parse_page2(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['pdf'] = response.url
        return item
```

You're creating new Requests with `item` as a meta element for each URL, you're then you're replacing that item's 'pdf' field, then yielding that item.  The end result: for each URL, you get a new duplicate item with a different PDF field.

As is, Scrapy has no way of knowing what you intend to do with the item.  You'll need to change your code to: A) keep track of all URLs, and only yield once they've all been processed, and B) append to `item['pdf']`, not overwrite it.